# Displaying success message after form is submitted

Tags: php, codeigniter

My form was working perfectly fine and displays the success message when the form is submitted. However, I just added a small piece of code and though the form submits, it doesn't display the success message anymore.

This is my code:

```
 public function entrymarks()
 {
 $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id', 'Subject', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

 if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
 $data = array(
 'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => form_error('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
 );
 $array = array('status' => 0, 'error' => $data);
 echo json_encode($array);
 } else {

 $exam_group_student_id = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_id');

 $insert_array = array();
 $update_array = array();
 if (!empty($exam_group_student_id)) {
 foreach ($exam_group_student_id as $exam_group_student_key => $exam_group_student_value) {
 $attendance_post = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_attendance_' . $exam_group_student_value);
 if (isset($attendance_post)) {
 $attendance = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_attendance_' . $exam_group_student_value);
 } else {
 $attendance = "present";
 }

 $cal1 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
 $cal2 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca2_' . $exam_group_student_value);
 $cal3 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca3_' . $exam_group_student_value);
 $cal4 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca4_' . $exam_group_student_value);
 $exam = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_exam_' . $exam_group_student_value);

 $total = $cal1 + $cal2 + $cal3 + $cal4 + $exam;

 if ($total > 0) {   // This line may be the problem
 $array = array(
 'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
 'exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id' => $exam_group_student_value,
 'attendence' => $attendance,
 'get_ca1' => $cal1,
 'get_ca2' => $cal2,
 'get_ca3' => $cal3,
 'get_ca4' => $cal4,
 'get_exam' => $exam,
 'get_tot_score' => $total,
 'note' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_note_' . $exam_group_student_value),

 );
 $insert_array[] = $array;
 }
 }
 }

 $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($insert_array);

 $array = array('status' => '1', 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
 echo json_encode($array);
 }
 }
```

How do I get the success message to display again?

Comment: explain what small piece of code you added, or remove it then as you say the success message will display again

Comment: if ($total > 0) is to prevent values of 0s from entering my table, so I can't remove it now. Perhaps I'm not closing the tag properly?